# Android and Checkout API for in app purchases

Tags: android

I want to know if its possible/legal(not against terms of service) to use the google checkout api for an android app to support in app purchases. The types of items being purchased would be something like extra coins where they can be purchased multiple times.

I know that this would require getting the user's credentials or pointing them to the checkout page or something. I want to know if its possible to do this within the app by opening a webview to the checkout process, and then getting a callback to a custom url on my server that will allow the app to see that the purchase was successful. Something like what the android market does for app purchases.

Thanks for any responses. I don't currently have code to show as I am researching into this before devoting time to create something I won't be able to use. Also maybe android will support native in-app purchases in newer versions of the sdk.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but if it is I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 3):

Spoke to (Android evangelist) Reto Meier at Google Tech Days about this and he said it is perfectly OK to do inter-app purchases in the market. You should comply to other regulations - most common is that you need to only buy content that is consumed on the mobile. Virtual "coins" are on quite thin ice, some countries ban issuing "virtual money" but you can do essentially the same with just little different paradigm. Hope this helps.

Comment: hey @pavel lahoda, are you sure that this can be done? if so, do you have a source code for it, or know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Android market documentation explicitly states that you can do check it.

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-refunds

> Important: You cannot use the Google Checkout API to issue refunds or
>   cancel in-app billing transactions. You must do this manually through
>   your Google Checkout merchant account. However, you can use the Google
>   Checkout API to retrieve order information.